# Bitbucket Server не показывает историю коммитов

Tags: git, bitbucket

Добавил репозиторий в Bitbucket Server, но в веб интерфейсе нет истории коммитов. При этом, если зайти в каталог репозитория на сервере, то коммиты там есть.

Если этот же репозиторий запушить в Bitbucket Cloud, то с историей все нормально.

Пробовал добавлять репозитории разными способами:

- Просто импортировал
- git push -u origin master
- git push --mirror origin

В настройках ничего не нашел.

Comment: А если из этого репозитория клонировать, будут коммиты? Может быть, веб-морда не на тот репозиторий смотрит?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в старой версии GIT на сервере.